# Android pass an instance of Asynctask object to another activity

Tags: java, android, serialization, android-asynctask

I have problem with passing my custom class of Asynctask to another activity. Custom class implements Serialization. I put object  to intent extra but I cant read it in another activity by getserializationextra.  there is exception no Serialization...  how to pass  this object?

**EDIT:**

this is my custom class extends AsyncTask:

```
public class LoginAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 41L;
 ....
 }
```

Activity class where I tried to pass object to another activity:

```
  Intent passToProfil = new Intent(Login.this, Profil.class);
    passToProfil.putExtra("LOGIN_ASYNCTASK", loginAsyncTask);
    passToProfil.putExtra("NEW_USER", user);
    startActivity(passToProfil);
    finish();
```

and activity where I tried to get object:

```
Intent getU = getIntent();
    loginAsyncTask=(LoginAsyncTask)getU.getSerializableExtra("LOGIN_ASYNCTASK");
```

and there is exception:

```
06-21 20:11:01.771 29697-29809/com.mmc.mateusz.gymbuddies E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.mmc.mateusz.gymbuddies.LoginAsyncTask)
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1279)
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1233)
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
                                                                            at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
                                                                            at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:6814)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1928)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1426)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3446)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:843)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3617)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3585)
                                                                            at com.mmc.mateusz.gymbuddies.Login.startProfil(Login.java:82)
                                                                            at com.mmc.mateusz.gymbuddies.Login.passUserToProfil(Login.java:124)
                                                                            at com.mmc.mateusz.gymbuddies.LoginAsyncTask.doInBackground(LoginAsyncTask.java:51)
                                                                            at com.mmc.mateusz.gymbuddies.LoginAsyncTask.doInBackground(LoginAsyncTask.java:16)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
                                                                         Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
                                                                            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1274)
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1233) 
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591) 
                                                                            at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619) 
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605) 
                                                                            at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:6814) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1928) 
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1426) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3446) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407) 
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:843) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3617) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3585) 
                                                                            at com.mmc.mateusz.gymbuddies.Login.startProfil(Login.java:82) 
                                                                            at com.mmc.mateusz.gymbuddies.Login.passUserToProfil(Login.java:124) 
                                                                            at com.mmc.mateusz.gymbuddies.LoginAsyncTask.doInBackground(LoginAsyncTask.java:51) 
                                                                            at com.mmc.mateusz.gymbuddies.LoginAsyncTask.doInBackground(LoginAsyncTask.java:16) 
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

line 82 is:

```
        startActivity(passToProfil);
```

line 16 is:

```
public class LoginAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements Serializable {
```

I have another User.class object where I implements in the same way Serialization and there is no problem. I need AsyncTask object to finish of login my user... so I need to pass to another activity so that pass object User to server.

Comment: Please share the code of your custom class that implements `Serializable` and the code where you pass it and read it. Thank you.

Comment: *I have problem with passing my custom class of Asynctask to another activity* bacuse it is not possible ... maybe you should use Serivice instead (in one Activity you start service, serice start the job, it can be binded in another activity later)

Comment: It sounds like you are attempting to start an `AsyncTask` in one Activity and then pass it to another Activity so that the result goes there instead. That's a major design issue, my friend. You don't want to do it like that. Instead, just get the result in your first Activity, then pass the actual result to the next Activity through the intent.